# A faster way for making developed cities in Civilization 5 SDK?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

The Civ 5 SDK makes modding and mapmaking extremely easy, but it has lots of limitations that have frustrated me. One of the most tedious things for me happens when making a scenario that occurs in a later era and requires more developed cities: having to manually add individual buildings and stats to each and every city.

For example, I am making a mod with a scenario that starts in the future era. In order for city stats to be realistic for that era, I need to manually check the boxes for every single building that is essential for prerequisite eras, such as granaries, markets, defensive structures, seaports, science buildings, etc. Otherwise, I would have an ancient era city in the future era and wouldn't be able to do anything useful with it.

It is very tedious and time consuming to manually add in this information to every single city on the map, and is the only thing holding me back from making really interesting and involved scenarios in mods. Is there a faster way to make developed cities in the SDK, such as copying cities, using templates for cities (for example, it would be really helpful if I could just place down a "future era city", similar to the developed city that is automatically created when founding a city in a later era) or using a Lua script?

If anyone can point out any features I may have missed about the SDK or has any suggestions, it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Civ 5 SDK, I couldn't find an option that would help in your particular case. I did however find something that you might not know, you can highlight a large selection of options and tick a single box to tick all of the highlighted options. Simply select an item, hold shift and click further up or down the list, then tick one box to tick all of the selected items. You can then control + click items to deselect/select them.

I had an idea on how I would go about creating a modification like this, you could ideally make an mod that automatically selects a predefined list from the city builder which can be modified and saved and then re-selected. I'm not familiar enough with LUA or the modification making tool to do this. While looking around the world maker I noticed the Mod tab (close to the cities tab) which has options for different mods to be applied to different tiles, there was an enumeration option but I'm not sure if you could apply it to the city.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdVPw.jpg)